# Display 'New' icon next to 'Title'

Tags: 2013, list, javascript

I have a home page displaying downloadable links from a List.

I am looking to achieve the following:

1) If status 'New' is chosen (See below) in the List:
[image]

2) The home page will display the 'New' icon beside the link title:

New icon:

[image]

http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-MdjCoL-zRqw/Vpj2wId1V8I/AAAAAAAAADA/6oVQLyVJG3Y/s1600/new_icon_blink_clearurupdates.gif

The final result i want to achieve:

[image]

Comment: Is it custom web part or the SharePoint list view that you are using in you home page?

Comment: Is that status selection for each link list item?

Comment: Yes, what webpart do you use for this task? List view, content query, etc.?

Comment: I am using javascript and SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite to display data from my list to the home page. When 'New' is selected on the list, my homepage should display the new .gif beside the title.

Comment: Then what value does your $().SPServices.SPGetListItemsJson return for "Status" field? I guess it should be "1" or "0".